# Angular mat-icon show on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

So I have the following html:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput id={{item.value.fieldID}} formControlName="view"
     placeholder={{item.value.displayname}} />
   <mat-error *ngIf="item.controls.view.valid"></mat-error>
   <button mat-button *ngIf="item.value.view" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clear(i, j)">
     <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
   </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm using a reactive form with FormArray. But besides that I got problem with the event on a formcontrol. Touched is a nice one.

I tried to use:

```
*ngIf="item.value.view && item.controls.view.touched"
(blur)="item.controls.view.markAsUntouched();"
(focus)="item.controls.view.markAsTouched();"
```

But when I click the button the blur will trigger before the button click, so the button dissapears before the click event happens.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can try to call the action inside a `setTimeout` on the ts file instead of calling it directly on the template.

Comment: @jpavel That's not an option since it's used for mobile and the older phone will make a timeout longer.

Comment: Can you give more details about what you want to achieve? It seems to be a close icon button that should appear when you hover the component, is that right? About the mobile device, you can do a `setTimeout` with a zero delay => we just want to put the action in the end of the line inside the event loop.

Comment: I want to clear the value in the input field only if it's focused. That's what the `clear(i,j)` `item.controls.view.patchValue('')` is doing. I thought the best way would be to do this with the icon on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. What happens is I call a different event the `mouseDown`. This event will trigger infront of the of the blur event and also not cancel it.

So what I changed was:

```
   <button mat-button *ngIf="item.value.view" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clear(i, j)">
     <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
   </button>
```

Into this (with the blur and focus event):

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="item.value.view && item.controls.view.touched" matSuffix (mousedown)="clear(i, j);">close</mat-icon>
```